# HTML page is shown with broken UI While publishing the extent report HTML file on Jenkins using the 'HTML Publisher Plugin'

Tags: jenkins-plugins, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

HTML page is shown with broken UI While publishing the extent report HTML file using the 'HTML Publisher Plugin', Can any one please guide me how can I print the complete report with proper UI

*Screenshot of the report when I open the html report using the HTML publisher plugin*

[image]

*Screenshot of the report when I open the same html report file using the Firefox browser*

[image]

Answer (score 10):

I was facing a similar issue when I was trying to view the extent report from Jenkins.

**Reason for this issue:**
The issue is because of the 'Content-Security-Policy' which is introduced in Jenkins from v1.641, It is blocking the inline CSS, JS Ajax resources to loaded

**Solution:** 
Change default Content Security Policy. Go to Manage Jenkins -> Script Console and type into console the following commands:

```
System.clearProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP");

System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "sandbox allow-scripts; default-src 'self'; script-src * 'unsafe-eval'; img-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; font-src *");
```

restart Jenkins after the above step

This worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution for the issue, Issue is because of the 'Content-Security-Policy' which is introduced in Jenkins from v1.641, It is blocking the inline css, JS Ajax resources to loaded

To overcome this issue we need to use 'java -Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP="" -jar jenkins.war' command to start Jenkins server from command prompt

Reference : https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Configuring+Content+Security+Policy#ConfiguringContentSecurityPolicy-HTMLPublisherPlugin

Answer (score 1):

Tried to sort this issue differently by Groovy using Pre Step to the build of the Jenkins Job.

1) Install Groovy plugin [https://plugins.jenkins.io/groovy]

2) Reach to your job --> Configure--> Pre Steps --> Execute it in an "Execute system Groovy Script" build step with this script:-

```
System.clearProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP")

System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "sandbox allow-same- 
origin allow-scripts;default-src *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; 
style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline' *; connect-src * 'self' data:; img-src 'self' 
data:;")

System.getProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP")
```

3) Under the "Build Triggers" section, select "Build Periodically" with this value: H 12 * * *

4) Run the Job--> GO to Console--> Check script has been executed like this below:

Script returned: sandbox allow-same-origin allow-scripts;default-src *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline' *; connect-src * 'self' data:; img-src 'self' data:;

**Note: Every time job is being executed, this property will be set beforehand and Extent Report will be populated correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below command for removing broken UI for extent Report.

1. Open your terminal.
2. Cd /etc/default
3. Open file
4. sudo vim jenkins
5. Add below command in file.
6. JAVA_ARGS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP="
7. Restart the jenkins server.
8. sudo service jenkins restart.

Comment: I'm not using Jenkins. Iam running my code from eclipse. Still i am getting the broken UI

Answer (score 0):

**Reason for this issue:** The issue is because of the 'Content-Security-Policy' which is introduced in Jenkins from v1.641, It is blocking the inline CSS, JS Ajax resources to loaded

**Solution**: Change default Content Security Policy. Go to Manage Jenkins -> Script Console and type into console the following commands:

```
System.clearProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP");
System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "sandbox allow-scripts; default-src 'self'; script-src * 'unsafe-eval'; img-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; font-src *");
```

restart Jenkins after the above step

This worked for me :)