# CI integration with Extent Reports using htmlpublisher

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, extentreports, extent

I am using HTML publisher plugin in Jenkins, and generating opening Extent Report.
By Report generated with Jenkin don't have UI. However when I open then manually they opens just fine.

[Click of Report Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SweJ.png)

Comment: You will find solution on github extent reports https://github.com/anshooarora/extentreports/issues/290

Comment: Also here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34892106/html-page-is-shown-with-broken-ui-while-publishing-the-extent-report-html-file-u

Comment: Detailed explanation: https://kb.froglogic.com/display/KB/Content+Security+Policy+(CSP)+for+Web+Report

Answer (score 4):

To change default Content Security Policy go to `Manage Jenkins -> Script Console` and add following commands:

```
System.clearProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP");

System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "sandbox allow-scripts; default-src 'self'; script-src * 'unsafe-eval'; img-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; font-src *");
```

Run the Build and View the report.

Comment: This fixed it for me (source https://kb.froglogic.com/display/KB/Content+Security+Policy+(CSP)+for+Web+Report): System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "sandbox allow-same-origin allow-scripts; default-src 'self'; script-src * 'unsafe-eval'; img-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; font-src *");

Answer (score 0):

Point out the `extent report file` (For example, Report.html) in the index page field and the `extent report directory` in the HTML Directory to archive field in the html publisher plugin configuration.

Answer (score -1):

Go to Manage Jenkins then to Script Console and paste this code:

`System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "")`

Then click run.

Now, rerun your build and check again. You should be able to see the UI of the report now

Comment: Disabling all CSP security is generally not considered a sound "solution"